# Android - Send javascript code to WebView's inside page

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a `WebView` in Form. And I am using this code.

```
WebView ww = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = ww.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ww.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

What I want is, when the page has finished loading, I want the my `TextView` value to be set on the search input box and start a search.

Firstly I think this code will work.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementsByID('masthead-search-term').value ='TEST1';};");
```

But when I use this code, I see only "TEST1" in all page.

Thanks for help from now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `textView1` to be the `TextView` where your query is.

Try the following code,

```
// Load the query to the search input
String query = textView1.getText().toString();
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('masthead-search-term').value ='" + query + "';};");

// For the click
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('search-btn').click();};");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementsByID('masthead-search').value ='TEST1';};");
```

I checked youtube's page and saw youtube's Search bar id is masthead-search. Secondly, If you run that it will just write **TEST1** in Search bar.

I did not understand your question correctly, pardon me for that however, I guess you asked whether it is possible to click that search button.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementsByID('masthead-search').value ='TEST1'.click();};");
```

I am not 100% sure. It's a try and error method. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like browser inserts into document value, that was returned by `javascript:` code in search bar. To avoid that you can wrap your call into function, like this:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('masthead-search-term').value ='TEST1';document.getElementById('masthead-search').submit();})()
```

Also pay attention, that it's `getElementById()`, not `getElementsByID()`

**P.S.** It is worth noting that you can achieve the same effect by just redirecting user to `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test1` url.